# c# Webcrawler optimization

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have Webcrawles writed in C#, it uses multithreading. For now it can download and parse about 1000 links / min but when I run ex. 3 instances at the same time every one instance can reach 1000 links / min so I have 3000 links/min. One instance uses up to 2% CPU, 100MB RAM, and 1% network speed. Now I wonder it is possible to one instance can reach 3000 links/min or more when I have avaialable resources (cpu,ram,network)?

Structure of my code:

```
ThreadSafeFileBuffer<string> successWriter = new ThreadSafeFileBuffer<string>("ok.txt");
IEnumerable<string> lines = File.ReadLines("urls.txt");
var options = new ParallelOptions
                                            {
                                                CancellationToken = _cts.Token,
                                                MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 500
                                            };

Parallel.ForEach(lines, options, (line, loopState, idx) =>
                                                {
var crawler = new Crawler(line);
var result = crawler.Go(); //download,parse
successWriter.AddResult(result);
}
```

I have Windows 7,CPU i7,16GB RAM,SSD disk

Comment: Notice that HEAD request method is faster than GET method. You can use HEAD instead of GET when appropriate.

Comment: @Mecek: HEAD is indeed faster than GET, but often not by much. It rather depends on the size of the data. The major part of many requests isn't the time to transfer the data, but rather the latency between request and response. In addition, a surprising number of servers return 404 for HEAD requests, or return headers that are different from the headers returned by GET. When you add in the time it takes to correctly handle the 404s, it becomes pretty much a wash. You're better off always using GET except on those sites that you know respond correctly to HEAD.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with using `Parallel.ForEach` on a list of URLs is that those lists often contain many URLs from the same site and you end up with multiple concurrent requests to the same site. Some sites frown on that and will block you or insert artificial delays.

1,000 requests per minute works out to 16 or 17 requests per second, which is pretty much the limit of what you can do without resorting to extraordinary measures. A large part of the problem is DNS resolution, which can take a surprisingly long time. In addition, the default .NET `ServicePointManager` limits you to 2 concurrent requests on any given site. If you want to support more than that, you need to change the [ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit.aspx) property.

You definitely don't want to add hundreds of threads. I did that once. It's painful. What you need is a handful of threads that can make asynchronous requests very quickly. My testing shows that a single thread can't sustain more than 15 requests per second because [HttpRequest.BeginGetResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse.aspx) does a lot of synchronous work before going asynchronous. As the documentation states:

> The BeginGetResponse method requires some synchronous setup tasks to complete (DNS resolution, proxy detection, and TCP socket connection, for example) before this method becomes asynchronous.

You can speed that up somewhat by increasing the size of your DNS client cache and by having a local DNS cache on a separate machine, but there's a limit to what you can achieve there.

I don't know how much crawling you're doing. If you're doing a lot, then you need to implement a politeness policy that takes into account the robots.txt file, limits how often it hits a particular site, limits the types of URLs it downloads (no use downloading an MP3 or .doc file if you can't do anything with it, for example), etc. To prevent your crawler from being blocked, your crawler becomes at the core a politeness policy enforcer that just happens to download web pages.

I started writing about this some time back, but then didn't finish (other projects took precedence). See http://blog.mischel.com/2011/12/13/writing-a-web-crawler-introduction/ for the first post and links to the other posts in the thread. Also see http://blog.mischel.com/2011/12/26/writing-a-web-crawler-queue-management-part-1/. It's something I've been wanting to get back to, but after almost two years I still haven't managed it.

You'll also run into [proxy problems](http://blog.mischel.com/2008/07/10/proxy-fits/), URL filtering problems ([here](http://blog.mischel.com/2008/07/19/more-url-filtering/) and [here](http://blog.mischel.com/2008/07/09/crawler-versus-the-urls/)), [weird redirects](http://blog.mischel.com/2008/05/15/a-variation-on-the-homegrown-dos-attack/), and [asynchronous calls that aren't completely asynchronous](http://blog.mischel.com/2008/06/10/is-this-really-asynchronous/).

Comment: That crawler blog is fascinating. Nice work!

Answer (score 1):

You do not need more threads, as those threads all spend their time waiting. You need an asynchronous program, that doesn't block threads waiting for web replies.

The problem with threads is that they are a rather expensive resource, because of the memory required for their stack, and the work they create for the OS thread scheduler. In your program, this scheduler keeps on switching threads to that they can all take turns waiting. But they're not doing anything usefull.

Comment: +1. More threads definitely is *not* the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. Find out where your bottleneck is and improve on the performance.

Edit:

If you are using Parallel.ForEach, you can try an overload using the [ParallelOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.aspx) parameter. Setting the MaxDegreeOfParallelism property might help.

Comment: Hard to find it:( I have simple Parallel.ForEach - every course of the loop parse one url - can it be problem with threads limit?

Comment: Already doing this but with high values - over 500 speed doesn't change

Answer (score 0):

In a webcrawler your going to be spending most of your time waiting for web requests. So if you have blocking I/O your program is not going to be processing at full speed, also async IO wont help if the program sits idle waiting for a callback. Sounds like you just need to add more threads to your main app and be processing in parallel.

But it's hard to tell, since you've not posted any code.,

Answer (score 0):

Actually the number of links/min is directly proportional with the number of crawler threads running at the same time.

In your first case; you have 3 processes with n threads per. (total 3n threads)

Try to run 3n threads in one process.

Actually this depends on your operating system and CPU, too. Because old versions of windows (like XP) doesn't support parallel multithreading over different cpu cores.

Comment: I tried with 500 and 1000 threds with ForEach loop but it doesn't change speed

Answer (score 0):

Parallelism with the TPL is bad design for a web crawler. A Parallel.ForEach() loop starts only a bunch of requests (5-50), because it is designed to perform time consuming computing in parallel and not to perform thousands of requests in parallel which almost do nothing. To get the data you want to have, you must be able to preform a really large amount (10000+) of requests in parallel. Async Operations are the key to that.

I have developed the Crawler Engine of the Crawler-Lib Framework. It is a workflow enabled crawler which can easily extended to do any kind of requests or even processing you want to have.
It is designed to give you high throughput out of the box.

Here is the engine: http://www.crawler-lib.net/crawler-lib-engine

Here are some Youtube Videos, showing how the Crawler-Lib engine works: http://www.youtube.com/user/CrawlerLib

I know this project is not open source, but there is a free version.